# Node JS request module does not send form data

Tags: node.js, express, post, request

I am making a post request using "request" module in node js like this:

```
 request.post({url: 'http://localhost:4004/api/v1/notifications/post', form: {msg:msg, userID:userID}}, function(err, httpResponse, body){
    if(err) return 0;
    else return 1;
});
```

no the server side I get the request, however the parameters do not come. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you get in the network tab ?

Comment: I do not do it through browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to stringify your form data and put it in the body. Here is a similar question that has been answered: [POST Requests not working using request module in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918285/post-requests-not-working-using-request-module-in-node-js)